# Where can I find Nokia Scrum Test?

Tags: agile, scrum

Is the Nokia Scrum test available online? I could find link to the modified Scrum test by Jeff Sutherland but unable to locate the link to original Scrum test by Nokia.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the [**first** Nokia test](http://jeffsutherland.com/basvodde2006_nokia_agile.pdf) developed by Bas Vodde while coaching teams at Nokia Networks in Finland. I'm pasting it below:

> #### No Agile & Iterative when:
>
> - **You know when you are not doing iterative development when:**
>
>   - Iterations are longer than 2-6 weeks
>   - Teams tries to complete specifications before programming
>   - An iteration does not include testing
>   - Iteration does not provide workable code
>   - Detailed (task level) plans and accurate estimates are expected at the
>       beginning of a project
>   - The iteration plan doesn't reflect what the team is doing
> - **You know you are not doing agile development when:**
>
>   - There is little co-operation within the team
>   - Design and code is produced in individual effort
>   - Progress is measured by hours spend or documents created instead of
>       working code
>   - Builds are done once in three weeks

#### Reference

- [Nokia Test: Where did it come from?](http://scrum.jeffsutherland.com/2008/08/nokia-test-where-did-it-come-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest other approaches. Nokia Scrum Test is very brief. You will not get details you need for further improvements.

To validate Scrum implementation in smal teams we use **Henrik Kniberg's Scrum Checklist**.
In case oyou would like to compare to 'world' check **Mike Cohn's ComparativeAgility.com** site.

[Read more here](http://www.scrumdesk.com/agile-adaption-gaps-identification/)